# Чому „біль“ чоловічого роду?

Tags: етимологія, рід

Чи існує якийсь обґрунт, чому *біль* є чоловічого роду?

За ознакою добре [вписується](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par44) як 3 відміна:

> **3 відміна**: іменники жін. роду з кінцевим приголосним основи: *вість*, *любов*, *міць*, *річ*, *розкіш*, *сіль*, *тінь*, а також слово *мати*, в якому при відмінюванні з’являється суфікс **ер**.

Хоча не заперечую про спорідненість з [м’якої групи чоловічого роду 2 відміни](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par45IIp2):

> До м’якої групи належать іменники чол. роду з кінцевим м’яким приголосним основи: *боєць*, *велетень*, *звичай*, *край*, *учитель*, *Бенедьо*; сюди належить частина іменників із суфіксами **ар**, **ир**, які в однині мають наголос на корені: *бондар* — *бондаря*, *козир* — *козиря*, *лікар* — *лікаря*, *писар* — *писаря*, а також іменники, у яких при відмінюванні наголос переходить із суфікса на закінчення: *буквар* — *букваря*, *вівчар* — *вівчаря*, *друкар* — *друкаря*, *інвентар* — *інвентарю*, *календар* — *календаря*, *кобзар* — *кобзаря*, *пролетар* — *пролетаря*, *секретар* — *секретаря*, *шахтар* — *шахтаря*; *гузир* — *гузиря*, *проводир* — *проводиря*, *пухир* — *пухиря* та ін.

Однак, на відміну жіночого роду, я бачу тут явні [нароски](//r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovotvir_narostky): староцерковний **тель** в *учитель*, **ень** (з випаднем **е**) в *велетень*, **й**/**ець** (**е** випадне) в *боєць*. Чого не мовити про *біль* та инших прикладових слів жіночого роду.

Answer (score 4):

В українській мові вистачає безсуфіксальних іменників чоловічого м'якої групи другої відміни:

- праслов'янських: *ву́гіль*, *день*, *джміль*, *коро́ль*, *край*, *о́кунь* <sub>не факт, що безсуфіксальне, можливо, від **oko* або **ak*, але зараз не сприймається як суфікс</sub>, *тать* <sub>застаріле</sub>, *хміль*, *я́тіль* <sub>діалектне</sub>;
- пізнішого утворення: *білль*, *водеві́ль*, *вухна́ль*, *кіль*, *кріль*, *курку́ль*, *паро́ль*, *цо́коль*, *чай*.

Те, що таких не наведено серед прикладів у «Правописі» — так перелік прикладів і не зобов'язаний бути всеохопним.

Але праслов'янське [*bolь*](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/bol%D1%8C) (також [*boljь*](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/bolj%D1%8C)) виводять жіночого роду.

Не виключаю, що Ваша теорія про суфікси може мати рацію — можливо, в якийсь момент частина кореня *-іль* у *біль* могла бути переосмислена як суфікс (аналогічний до *-іль* у *березі́ль* <sub>застаріле</sub>, *ва́жіль*, *кисі́ль*).

Comment: Гм, цьікаво, ланка про прасловјаньське вказује: **південь**, 4 сучасних: окрім словенів, всьуди жіночиј рід, але з цим балґарська (окреме діјалектне слово) і себрохорватська мајуть і чоловічого, несучасноју је церковнословјаньська — жіночиј; **схід**, 3 мови: лиш москальі мајуть жіночого, дльа русиньськојі, шчо је діјалектом украјиньськојі, не вказали; **захід**, 6 мов: лиш півдньосорбська маје жіночого. Суттьевиј перехід виходить.

Comment: Існує ще ряд іменників, що змінили парадигму відмінювання із жіночого роду на чоловічий: дробь -> дріб, корь -> кір, насыпь -> насип і т.д.

Comment: @PaulGor ну, тут простїше, бо відкинули *ь*, з винятків шипячі, переважно на *ч*: *ніч*, *піч*.

Answer (score 1):

Перш за все, потрібно зазначити, що рід слова "біль" буде залежити від значення ([джерело](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C)):

> БІЛЬ1, болю, ч. Відчуття фізичного страждання. Біль без язика, але
>   каже, де болить (Укр.. присл.., 1955, 145); Він аж застогнав від болю
>   (Вовчок, І, 1955, 445); Що то за біль голови у Вас, чи це біль не
>   нервового характеру? (Коцюб., III, 1956, 399); Прокинувся Арсен
>   Черкашин з тупим болем у голові, з гірким тягарем у серці (Дмит.,
>   Розлука, 1957, 5); * У порівн. Самота, як біль зубів, почина ссать
>   йому серце (Коцюб., II, 1955, 330); // Відчуття прикрості, образи,
>   смутку. Буденне життя з його болем та горем, з його радощами та
>   утратами краще і докладніше укладається під прозою (Мирний, V, 1955,
>   377); З болем у серці згадав Силантьев, що техгурток.. працює кволо
>   (Донч., II, 1956, 117).
>
> БІЛЬ2, і, ж., рідко. 1. Білі нитки, біла пряжа. Усю ніч не спала. Та
>   біль сукала; По горі ходила. Біль білила (Нар. лірика, 1956, 351);
>   Сорочка "навипуск", мережана біллю, з виложистим коміром (Л. Укр.,
>   III, 1952, 193).
>
> 2. Яскраво-білий колір; білість. Чи тільки справді то сніги біліють? А може то розжеврілася туга, як те залізо., що біліє біллю..? (Л. Укр.,
>      І, 1951, 228); * У порівн. Як біль біла спочивала [Ілашка] по чорних
>      муках (Черемш., Тв., 1960, 67).
>
> БІЛЬ3, і, ж. Біла іржа - хвороба хрестоцвітих, що спричиняється до
>   появи білих блискучих плям на листках, стеблах, квітках і плодах
>   рослини. Біль, або біла іржа хрестоцвітих. При цій хворобі на листках,
>   стеблах, квітках і плодах з'являються білі блискучі плями (Шкідн. і
>   хвор. с.-г. рослин, 1956, 224).

Також варто зазначити цікавий факт, що деякі іменники в літературні мові належать до одного роду, а в розмовній - до іншого (однак, слова "біль" це не стосується). Крім того, у цьому [джерелі](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/cholovichyj-chy-zhinochyj-rid), звідки взята дана інформація, також підноситься питання роду слова "біль":

> «Спогад про неї стискає біллю»; «Я не хочу знов чіпати біллю сповнені
>   серця», — читаємо інколи в сучасній поезії й прозі, де автори забули,
>   що іменник біль в українській мові — чоловічого, а не жіночого роду
>   (пор. у російській мові душевная, зубная боль). Ця помилка трапляється
>   й у публіцистичних виступах, дарма що наша класика й народна мова
>   знали слово біль тільки як іменник чоловічого роду: «Вона чула
>   страшенний біль, страшну втому в цілім тілі» (І. Франко); «Чужий біль
>   нікому не болить» (прислів’я).