# Нова Самарь чи Нова Самар

Tags: етимологія, власні-назви, відмінювання, мʼякий-знак

Новомосковською міською радою було прийнято за основу [проект рішення](https://novomoskovsk-rada.dp.gov.ua/vsi-normativni-akti/pro-pereimenuvannia-mista-novomoskovsk-dnipropetrovskoi-oblasti-na-misto-nova-samar) від 20.12.2023 р. про перейменування міста **[Новомосковськ](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA)** на **Нова Самарь**.

Проте велика кількість українських ЗМІ опублікувала новину про перейменування міста на **Нова Самар**, нехтуючи правилами Українського правопису? Чи ніт?

Шановну спільноту прошу навести правила, відповідно до яких формуються складні власні назви в українській мові та провідмінювати її.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Згідно з сучасним правописом (це стосується не лише правопису 2019 року, а й значно старіших), м'який знак після *р* на кінці слова справді не пишуть:

> #### [§ 27](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/%202019.pdf#page=21). Коли не пишемо *Ь*
>
> *Ь* не пишемо:
>
> 1. Після *р* у кінці складу або слова: <…>, *кобза́р*, <…>, *лі́кар*, *монасти́р*, <…>, *секрета́р*, <…>, *школя́р*, <…>.

Усі наведені приклади чоловічого роду — вони належать до II відміни (але теж показні, бо частина цих слів історично мала м'який знак і тепер належить до [м'якої групи відмінювання](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/%202019.pdf#page=81)). Але правило про м'який знак після *р* так само стосується і до слів жіночого роду — вони потрапляють до III відміни й відмінюються відповідно ([коротка таблиця](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/%202019.pdf#page=82), [докладніше](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/%202019.pdf#page=100)):

| Відмінок | Однина | Множина |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Називний | глазу́р, твар | глазу́рі, тва́рі |
| Родовий | глазу́рі, тва́рі | глазу́рей, тва́рей |
| Давальний | глазу́рі, тва́рі | глазу́рям, тва́рям |
| Знахідний | глазу́р, твар | глазу́рі, тва́рей |
| Орудний | глазу́р'ю, тва́р'ю | глазу́рями, тва́рями |
| Місцевий | глазу́рі, тва́рі | глазу́рях, тва́рях |
| Кличний | глазу́ре, тваре | глазу́рі, тва́рі |

(До цієї ж відміни належить іменник *ма́ти* (*біома́ти*, *прама́ти*) і його застаріло-урочистий варіант *[ма́тір](/q/7154)* (*Богома́тір*, *прама́тір*), але там є певні відхилення у відмінюванні, зокрема родовий відмінок множини — *матері́в*.)

Upd.:

| Відмінок | Однина |
| --- | --- |
| Називний | Нова Самар |
| Родовий | Нової Самарі |
| Давальний | Новій Самарі |
| Знахідний | Нову Самар |
| Орудний | Новою Самар'ю |
| Місцевий | Новій Самарі |
| Кличний | Нова Самаре |

Comment: @Sútnôstj, слушно! Це жіночий рід, III відміна, а я чомусь зациклився на букварях/крамарях.

Comment: Отже, таки українські ЗМІ виявилися фаховими, а помилка міститься в поданні до Верховної Ради? Чи могли б ви провести етимологічний аналіз слова Самар, щоб остаточно визначити це він чи вона?

Comment: І провідмінювати саме “Нова Самар".  Щоб школяри ексНовомосковська мали надійне джерело інформації і 12-ки з укр.мови :)

Comment: @RomanMikhol, «таки українські ЗМІ виявилися фаховими, а помилка міститься в поданні до Верховної Ради?» — так (принаймні згідно з чинним правописом). Відмінювання саме Нової Самарі додав. Про етимологію та рід, на жаль, нічого додати не можу (у Вікіпедії пишуть, що жіночий, і в законопроєкті подано як жіночий, хоча суто теоретично могли й помилитися; там висувають [версії і щодо етимології](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Самар_(місто)#Етимологія), але я недостатньо компетентний, щоб судити, наскільки вони надійні).

Comment: @Sasha etymologija korısna štuka, ale ne jeʼ vırêšaljnoju. Tomu ce ne kritıčno. Naprıklad [*bôlj*](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/4664/585) — historıčno bulo žônočoho rodu, ale narazê v standartnij ukrajınsjkij čerez jakisj pevni prıčın — čolovêčoho.